# Can someone help me get my AES encryption working between Java, Javascript and C#?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, encryption, aes

I've already got it working between Java and Javascript, but the C# code does not work the same.  That is, given a specific string to encrypt, the Java and Javascript code will generate the same result, but the C# code generates a different result.

Here is the Javascript code (which uses CryptoJS):

```
AesUtil.prototype.encrypt = function(salt, iv, passPhrase, plainText) {
    var key = this.generateKey(salt, passPhrase);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            plainText,
            key,
            { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) });
    return encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
}
```

This code will encrypt "guest" as "WsH/YEUqqrWDxD15zxsUPg==".

Here is the Java code:

```
public String encrypt(String plainText, String salt, String passphrase, String iv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    //byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(salt);
    SecretKey key = generateKey(salt, passphrase);
    byte[] ivBytes = hex(iv);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypt(plainTextbytes,key, ivBytes));//, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private static SecretKey generateKey(String salt, String passphrase) {
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), hex(salt), 10000, 128);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "Rijndael");
        return key;
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw fail(e);
    }
    catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw fail(e);
    }
}
public static String hex(byte[] bytes) {
    return Hex.encodeHexString(bytes);
}
```

This code also encrypts "guest" to "WsH/YEUqqrWDxD15zxsUPg==".

Here is my C# code:

```
public String Encrypt(String plainText, String passphrase, String salt, String iv, int iterations) {
    var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetSymmetricAlgorithm(passphrase, salt, iv, iterations)));
}

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, SymmetricAlgorithm sa) {
    return sa.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
}

public SymmetricAlgorithm GetSymmetricAlgorithm(String passphrase, String salt, String iv, int iterations) {
    var saltBytes = new byte[16];
    var ivBytes = new byte[16];
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcdb = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), iterations);
    saltBytes = rfcdb.GetBytes(16);
    var tempBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
    Array.Copy(tempBytes, ivBytes, Math.Min(ivBytes.Length, tempBytes.Length));
    var rij =  new RijndaelManaged(); //SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
    rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    rij.FeedbackSize = 128;
    rij.KeySize = 128;
    rij.BlockSize = 128;
    rij.Key = saltBytes;
    rij.IV = ivBytes;
    return rij;
}

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, SymmetricAlgorithm sa) {
    return sa.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
}
```

This code encrypts "guest" to "F8t0D0vA2rxU3Ez1O5artA==".  Notice that the resulting value is the same length, but it's not the same value, and is not decryptable by the Java code (which I haven't provided here -- I'm mainly concerned with getting all three encryptions to be the same).

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats are the passphrase, salt and iv that you use to test the code?

Comment: What bdn02 said.  It would be helpful to provide those in order for potential responders not being forced to implement tests in three different languages in order to internally verify their own results.

Comment: I am not free to give those out.  I'm sorry.  The salt is a string of 64 characters that are all hex digits ('0' - 'F').  The IV is a string of 32 characters that are all hex digits.  The passphrase is four characters.

Sorry, wasn't done typing and hit enter...

If you use the same values for all three situations, you will get the same encrypted value for the Java and Javascript cases, but a different encrypted value for C#.

Comment: You should have used a test password and IV and not something that might be in production.

Comment: Good point.  None of this is in production at the moment though... it's a product in development.  Anyway, thanks again for the answer you provided with solved my problem.  I now have code in C#, Java and Javascript that's all compatible with respect to password encryption!  I couldn't be happier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decode the IV from hex in JS and Java, but in C# you have `var tempBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);`. You would need to do the same Hex decoding in C#.

Comment: THANKS!  That was it!!  I would buy you a beer if I could!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Haha :) but you should hold the horses. You're not done yet, because you probably need to authenticate your ciphertexts to prevent tampering or attacks such as padding oracle attack. [Why should I use Authenticated Encryption instead of just encryption?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12178/13022) I don't think you need to implement everything yourself, because [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) has a lot of this implemented, but I don't know if the JavaScript version is usable and feature complete.